# different color scales for same aesthetic in different layers in ggplot2, without unstable packages

Tags: r, ggplot2

is it possible to have multiple color scales for different layers?

I emulated what I would like to archive by using a fill aesthetic for a `geom_point` with `shape=21` in the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(
  x=c(1:4, 1:4),
  y=c(1:4, 2:5),
  a=factor(c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b")),
  A=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
)

ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=A), size=2) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=a), shape=21, colour=rgb(1,1,1,0), size=4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(a="red", b="blue"),
  ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c(A="green", B="yellow"),
  )
```

Why is this useful? An example would be: you have a quantity (y) measured over time (x) for different measurement units (first color scale) using a different method of measurement (second color scale)

In this case I can do with the workaround in the example but I think this is interesting in general.

Also of course having different scales for different layers does not make sense for all layers, scaling one layer's x axis logarithmically an the other one's linearly would not make sense in the most cases.

---

**Edit:** I can only use more or less stable packages, anything that might no longer be supported or changes its interface often does not work.

Comment: google "several scales for same aesthetic ggplot" - plenty of threads. Check the ggnewscale package, I guess that's what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have different scales the same aesthetic (color) in different geoms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166901/how-to-have-different-scales-the-same-aesthetic-color-in-different-geoms)

Comment: the above is just one of those

Comment: Thanks for your replies, the packages look good but both packages state in their first paragraph that they are highly experimental, which disqualifies them for my current usecase.

Comment: ggnewscale is on CRAN, this makes it fairly solid

Comment: If you're worried about reproducibility of your code, check the [groundhog package](https://groundhogr.com) - it allows you to reproduce your code based on the exact package versions when you have created the script.

Comment: Being on CRAN does not make the interfaces of the package stable. Yes it will unlikely give errors in the current form, yes it will be available, but updates can still break things. 

I tried packages like packrat but there were always problems due to our samba mount not supporting symlinks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set multiple legends / scales for the same aesthetic in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-scales-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement about "stable package" is somewhat vague, and I am surprised to hear that a CRAN package would not fulfil your requirement.

There is currently no vanilla ggplot2 way to achieve what you want and given the availability of the packages below, I don't think this is likely to come.

There are, as of today (December 2021), to my knowledge, "only" three packages available to allow creation of more than one scale for the same aesthetic. These are

- [the relayer package](https://github.com/clauswilke/relayer) (maintainer Claus Wilke) - not on CRAN
- [the ggh4x package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggh4x/index.html) (on CRAN, maintainer Teun van den Brand)
- [the ggnewscale package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggnewscale) (on CRAN, maintainer Elio Campitelli)

I use the latter a lot and never had problems, so I think this would be a very good package for your simple use case.

Comment: Thank you, a vanilla ggplot solution would have been the best, but this should work and thank you for writing this up in an answer